# Two constructor in apex controller

Tags: apex, controller

Just curious to know what will happen if I have an apex controller with two constructors. Something like this:

```
public wrapperAccountOpportunity(){
    fetchData();
}

public wrapperAccountOpportunity(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    this.account = (Account)controller.getRecord();
}
```

Will the first constructor call `fetchdata()` ?
In my case it is not calling the method but the other constructor is calling the method.

Why doesn't the first constructor invoke `fetchdata()` ?

Thanks in Advance !!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your page is written like this:

```
<apex:page controller="wrapperAccountOpportunity" ...
```

Then the zero-parameter constructor will be called.

If your page is written like this:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="wrapperAccountOpportunity" ...
```

Then the constructor with the single parameter `ApexPages.StandardController` will be called.

If you want to call `fetchData()` from both constructors, you'll have to call it from both constructors. Only one constructor will ever be called per controller or extension.

Consider the following code:

```
public with sharing class C {
    public C() {
        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO, 'Zero-constructor called'));
    }
    public C(C controller) {
        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO, 'Single-argument C called'));
    }
}
```

And, given the following page:

```
<apex:page controller="C" extensions="C">
    <apex:messages />
</apex:page>
```

You may expect both constructors to be called, but instead, you'll find only the zero-length (default) constructor is called, since the class is referenced twice. In this sense, classes that become controllers are actually singletons in Visualforce. The controller version of the class is only instantiated once; it can still be constructed normally multiple times within the code itself, but Visualforce will only instantiate one automatically.

Comment: It means we can call only one constructor in controller ?

Comment: @PrabhatKumar Visualforce will call just the first one it encounters per class, as per my example, but you can call constructors from other constructors using the `this` keyword.